# Read Data From The Byte Array Returned From Web Service

Tags: vb.net

I have a web service,which return data in byte array.Now i want to read that data in my console project.How can i do that,i already add the desire references to access that web service.I am using vb.net VS2012.Thanks.My web service method is as follow.

```
Public Function GetFile() As Byte()
        Dim response As Byte()
        Dim filePath As String = "D:\file.txt"
        response = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
        Return response
    End Function
```

Comment: How would you like to display to look? How does the Web Service encode the data? Is the file a text file? What encoding does the file use?

Comment: I want to read the content of file returned by web service in console.Encoding is base64Binary

Comment: So, the web service returns a `Byte()` containing the bytes of Base64 encoded `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
Dim result As String

Using (Dim data As New MemoryStream(response))
    Using (Dim reader As New StreamReader(data))
        result = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using    
End Using
```

if you knew the encoding, lets say it was UTF-8 you could do,

```
Dim result = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(response)
```

---

Following on from your comments, I think you are asserting this.

```
Dim response As Byte() 'Is the bytes of a Base64 encoded string.
```

So, we know all the bytes will be valid ASCII (because its Base64,) so the string encoding is interchangable.

```
Dim base64Encoded As String = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(response)
```

Now, `base64Encoded` is the string Base64 representation of some binary.

```
Dim decodedBinary As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded)
```

So, we've changed the encoded base64 into the binary it represents. Now, because I can see that in your example, you are reading a file called `"D:/file.txt"` I'm going to make the assumption that the contents of the file is a character encoded string, but I don't know the encoding of the string. The `StreamReader` class has some logic in the constructor that can make an educated guess at character encoding.

```
Dim result As String

Using (Dim data As New MemoryStream(decodedBinary))
    Using (Dim reader As New StreamReader(data))
        result = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using    
End Using
```

Hopefully, now `result` contains the context of the text file.

Comment: Kindly help me.I am badly struck

Comment: I've expanded the answer, after your comments, its still not exactly clear what your question is.